# Split JavaScript URL jQuery

Tags: jquery, join, onclick, split

An anchor in my HTML has an `onclick` attribute like so:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('/help_options.asp?ID=23', 350, 250);" class="help_question_mark">?</a>
```

I'm trying to strip away the JavaScript handlers to get the bare URL and prop it to the `href` attribute so the result would look like this:

```
 <a href="/help_options.asp?ID=23" class="help_question_mark">?</a>
```

I figured it'd be simple, just write something like this:

```
$('a.help_question_mark').each(function(){
  help_question_mark_link = $(this).attr('onclick').split('javascript:OpenNewWindow(\'').join('').split('\', 350, 250);').join('');
  $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
  $(this).attr('href',help_question_mark_link);
});
```

In jQuery 1.1.1, this seems to work, but not in 1.4.2 which I am limited to using.

Can anybody shed some light on this, I'm in a pickle.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa5N5/).

Comment: Maybe this will help explain what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/wa5N5/1/ basic debugging.

Comment: How exactly is it not working?  Are there errors or is it just doing nothing?

Comment: @KevinB Not sure how that helps. Even more basic debugging is jsHint error `Script URL` that I do not know how to get around.

Comment: @SuperScript Nothing at all. It's breaking JavaScript altogether.

Comment: @henryaaron my point is the string you are getting from .attr() isn't what you think it is. that's why the .split doesn't work the way you expect it to. i suggest cross-browser testing it too, you may get different results based on browser.

Comment: @henryaaron The errors are shown in the [error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). If it's "breaking JS altogether" then there *are* errors there.

Comment: Hmmm... I just threw your code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/mH54F/) and it worked just fine.  **The problem with your JSFiddle is that you have not event included jQuery.**

Comment: @SuperScript As did I, the problem only occurred when I loaded jQuery 1.4.2 in the side panel. It a real tease.

Comment: @henryaaron : ???, I don't see jQuery 1.4.2 as an option in JSFiddle.

Comment: @SuperScript External resources: http://jsfiddle.net/wa5N5/. And yes, the jQuery comes before the `<script>` element. Also, please calm yourself down, this is not some careless mistake

Comment: @KevinB Understood, I'm just really confused as far as jQuery 1.1.1 vs. 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  So after much fiddling I discovered that jQuery 1.4.2 returns a special onclick object when you call `$(...).attr('onclick')`, not just a string.

So we need to break away from jQuery use this:

```
this.getAttribute('onclick')
```

instead of this:

```
$(this).attr('onclick')
```

Just plain weird.  **See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/wa5N5/3/).**

P.S. I found this out by `console.log`ing the value returned by `$(...).attr('onclick')`.

Comment: And this is likely due to jquery retrieving properties rather than attributes with .attr() in older versions.

Comment: That's interesting, didn't take much out of that console.log, it all look pretty normal to me. Much obliged